# How to slice an array that is an observable?

Tags: mobx

I have the following observable

```
  @observable private _nodes: ValidNode[] = [];
```

how can I turn it into a simple array, by doing

```
this._nodes.slice();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.slice()` is totally fine to convert observable array back to plain JS array.

There is also `mobx.toJS()` util function, which can convert any observable data to plain JS format, it also works recursively.

[More in the docs](https://mobx.js.org/api.html#tojs)